# gulp-header only inject if it is not there already?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-header

Does anyone know how to accomplish only injecting the header if it not already there?

I am using the gulp-header plugin:

```
  injectCopyright() {
    return gulp.src([
      `${config.distDir}/**/*.js`,
      `${config.distDir}/**/*.css`,
      '!' + `${config.distVendorJsDir}/**`
    ])
      .pipe(header('/*\n' + copyright + '\n*/\n'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir));
  }
```

Every time the above gulp task runs however it injects the copyright each time adding a new one every time. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Easy: don't read the files from the same directory that you write them to.

Comment: But that is where the files are? confused by this can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: The files are there because you put them there. Just put them somewhere else.

Comment: Or add the copyright before you put them there. Then you can get rid of the entire task. Either way reading/writing files from/to the same directory is generally a bad idea in gulp.